# Comparing N arrays with N total values

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, lets say I have an array that looks something like this

```
[ [ -1, -1, 7, -1 , -1 ], [ -1, 7, -1, 7, -1], [-1, 7, -1, 7, -1], [-1, 7, -1, 7, 7]]
```

The amount of embedded arrays could always be different(0-n) and the amount of values contained within each array can also be different. What would be the best way to search all values in array index 0, then 1, then so on?

I know I could do some embedded for and while loops to accomplish this, just not sure if there is a cleaner or easier way to accomplish this task

Edit: added a longer array string to help clarify. In the example above, I am hoping to find a way to output that in all arrays at index 0 there is a common value

Edit 2:
Basically looking for a way to shorten this, or better way of accomplishing this

```
newArray = [];
output = [];
for(x = 0; x < array_inner[0].length; x++){
  for(i = 0; i < array_list.length; i++){
    newArray[x].push(array_inner[x])
}}

const allEqual = arr => arr.every(val => val === arr[0]);
for(p = 0; = p < newArray.length; p++){
  var result = allEqual(newArray[p])
  output.push(result)
}
```

Comment: Will the array only every be two levels deep? And are you looking to change the array or just iterate over each item?

Comment: Yeah, thats correct

Comment: do you want to check if a certain value exists in these arrays ?

Comment: do you have a greater exampel and the wanted result?

Comment: Just edited to hopefully add more clarification

Comment: What would be the result be for `[[-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 2]]` be if all sub arrays are checked for index `0`?

Comment: I'm looking for any indexes that equal -1 across all arrays within the array.

Comment: does it have to equal -1  ,

Comment: Yeah. The end result is to find anywhere in the list of arrays where a -1 shows up in an index across all arrays

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this ?

```js
const arrays=[ [ -1, -1, 7 ], [ -1, 7, -1,2 ],[-1,7,1],[1,5,9,9] ]
const valueToSearch=7
let index= 0


let indexesOutput= arrays.reduce((a,c)=> {
 console.log( c.filter(n=>n==-1))
 return [...arrays[index++]]
} ,[])
```

Comment: Sorta, except I am looking for any values across N arrays that are equal. 

So in this example. I would want to find out that both of the arrays have index 0 at -1.

[ [ -1, -1, 7 ], [ -1, 7, -1 ] ]